# How do I insert data from a reference table to the corresponding field

Tags: mysql, database, insert, web2py

I'm sorry if my question sounds confusing.I just started learning web2py recently,in this exercise I'm trying to make a simple users management webpage with the admin can assign the users theirs work lists,note and deadline

```
db.define_table('auth_manager',Field('name','string',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))
db.define_table('manager',Field('user','string','reference user.name'),
             Field('workname','text',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
             Field('deadline','date'),)
db.manager.deadline.requires=IS_DATE_IN_RANGE(format=T('%Y-%m-%d'),
                                          minimum=now,maximum=now+datetime.timedelta(60))
```

I thought of adding the manager's username in auth_manager table using appadmin's new record function.This is my user table

```
db.define_table('user',Field('name','string',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
             Field('password','password'),
             Field('workname','text'),                               
             Field('deadline','date'),                               
             format='%(name)s')
```

I wanted to insert workname and deadline into user table right after I add those form on manager but I couldn't find any other methods except the update or update_or_insert functions but both don't work because those fields can't be empty and their ids aren't the same value and multiple references to a single table don't work .

One last question,I want to use web2py's RBAC but the first & last name fields are often unnecessary if I want to use a full name field is there other way to do it?

Sorry for the long post,I hope I made my question clear.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to do, but I suspect you can make the built-in Auth system work for you. I suggest opening a discussion on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py) explaining in more detail what you are trying to achieve. Also, note that reference fields reference a table, not a specific field within that table -- they store the primary key of the referenced table, which is the `id` field (so, you would use `reference user` rather than `reference user.name`).

Comment: thank you,I asked a friend yesterday and also got the same answer,I'll try to make it clear next time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tables from `auth` and let web2py to handle everything in between.

The following code should resolve your problem:

```
db.define_table('manager', 'reference auth_user'),
                Field('workname', 'text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('deadline', 'date'))
```